# Merging two dataframes based on first two columns with the same information arranged differently in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I want to merge two data frames based on first two columns and their values, however, these values in the these columns can be switched between the columns according to dataset. So `merge` or `left_join` functions in `dplyr` package can't see that the pairwise information is the same.

For a better explanation, I defined two hypothetical datasets here:

```
tree.dat1 = data.frame(tree1 = factor(c(rep(33,3),rep(22,2),11)),
+                       tree2 = factor(c(22,11,44,11,44,44)),
+                       value = c(0.02, rep(0.03,3), rep(0.01,2)))

> tree.dat1
   tree1 tree2 value
1    33    22  0.02
2    33    11  0.03
3    33    44  0.03
4    22    11  0.03
5    22    44  0.01
6    11    44  0.01

tree.dat2 = data.frame(tree1 = factor(c(rep(11,3),rep(33,2),22)),
+                        tree2 = factor(c(22,33,44,22,44,44)),
+                        value1 = c(rep(3,0.05),0.02,rep(0.03,2)))
> tree.dat2
  tree1 tree2 value1
1    11    22   0.02
2    11    33   0.03
3    11    44   0.03
4    33    22   0.02
5    33    44   0.03
6    22    44   0.03
```

As you can see the pairwises of the first two column is the same, however, order of them different. So I want to create a new data set by using this information in the first two columns and keeping the both third columns in these data sets.

So:

```
> tree.dat3 = left_join(tree.dat1,tree.dat2, by = c("tree1","tree2"))
> tree.dat3
   tree1 tree2 value value1
1    33    22  0.02   0.02
2    33    11  0.03     NA
3    33    44  0.03   0.03
4    22    11  0.03     NA
5    22    44  0.01   0.03
6    11    44  0.01   0.03
```

I have two NAs values in the end, however, when I check the pairwise tables, I can see the information for 33 - 11 (or 22 - 11) pairwise is given in the `tree.dat1` dataset.

So the expected output is:

```
   tree1 tree2 value value1
1    33    22  0.02   0.02
2    33    11  0.03   0.03
3    33    44  0.03   0.03
4    22    11  0.03   0.02
5    22    44  0.01   0.03
6    11    44  0.01   0.03
```

So probably I am looking for some other way to merge the two dataframe to check the pairwise information rather than the factor levels in two columns. Because 33 - 11 and 11 - 33 is the same, but the values are different in the third columns. I would like to know a suitable way to do it for big datasets. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: I have edited the question with the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since order doesn't matter for the join, let's created a `TreeID` column where we sort `tree1` and `tree2`, so that the number pairs always come in the same order.

This is easier if your data isn't encoded as `factor`, because taking `min/max` of a factor doesn't work, and you have to coerce to character, then numeric to get it to work normally. If you need to do that with your source data, `as.numeric(as.character(tree.dat1$tree))` will do the trick. You *can* take the max of the `character` vector without converting to `numeric`, but I prefer not to because `max("11","2")` does not perform as you might expect.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

tree.dat1 = data.frame(tree1 = c(rep(33,3),rep(22,2),11),
                       tree2 = c(22,11,44,11,44,44),
                       value = c(0.02, rep(0.03,3), rep(0.01,2)))

tree.dat2 = data.frame(tree1 = c(rep(11,3),rep(33,2),22),
                       tree2 = c(22,33,44,22,44,44),
                        value1 = c(rep(3,0.05),0.02,rep(0.03,2)))
```

Construct `TreeID` by combining the min and max values of `tree1` and `tree2`. We use `rowwise()` to take the max and min value for each row, rather than each column.

```
tree.dat1 <- tree.dat1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(TreeID= str_c(min(tree1, tree2), max(tree1,tree2)))

tree.dat2 <- tree.dat2 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(TreeID= str_c(min(tree1, tree2), max(tree1,tree2)))

left_join(tree.dat1, tree.dat2, by = "TreeID")


Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 6 x 7
  tree1.x tree2.x value TreeID tree1.y tree2.y value1
    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1      33      22  0.02 2233        33      22   0.02
2      33      11  0.03 1133        11      33   0.03
3      33      44  0.03 3344        33      44   0.03
4      22      11  0.03 1122        11      22   0.02
5      22      44  0.01 2244        22      44   0.03
6      11      44  0.01 1144        11      44   0.03
```

To match your desired output exactly:

```
left_join(tree.dat1, tree.dat2, by = "TreeID") %>% select(-tree1.y, -tree2.y, -TreeID) %>% 
  rename(tree1 = tree1.x, tree2 = tree2.x)

  tree1 tree2 value value1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1    33    22  0.02   0.02
2    33    11  0.03   0.03
3    33    44  0.03   0.03
4    22    11  0.03   0.02
5    22    44  0.01   0.03
6    11    44  0.01   0.03
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is not just working right for this part of my work, also great solution to use the data in plots!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution. Factors may complicate your problem. If you have to use them, maybe convert to characters in your project.

```
tree.dat1 = data.frame(tree1 = (c(rep(33,3),rep(22,2),11)),
                       tree2 = (c(22,11,44,11,44,44)),
                       value = c(0.02, rep(0.03,3), rep(0.01,2)))

tree.dat2 = data.frame(tree1 = (c(rep(11,3),rep(33,2),22)),
                        tree2 = (c(22,33,44,22,44,44)),
                        value1 = c(rep(3,0.05),0.02,rep(0.03,2)))

tree.dat1$id=apply(tree.dat1[,1:2], 1, function(x)paste(sort(x), collapse="-"))
tree.dat2$id=apply(tree.dat2[,1:2], 1, function(x)paste(sort(x), collapse="-"))

tree.dat3 = left_join(tree.dat1,tree.dat2[,3:4], by = "id")[,-4]


> tree.dat3
  tree1 tree2 value value1
1    33    22  0.02   0.02
2    33    11  0.03   0.03
3    33    44  0.03   0.03
4    22    11  0.03   0.02
5    22    44  0.01   0.03
6    11    44  0.01   0.03
```

Comment: Thanks for the R base solution. it is useful.